# Detect if MySQL has duplicates when inserting

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, duplicates

I have a table with the columns value1, value2 and value3.

Every few months, all rows will need to change their 'value1' to a different value. So far I have the following code and I cannot figure out for the life of me why it is not working. Instead of only modifying column one, it generates an entire new row of information.

Thanks in advance.

```
INSERT INTO table (value1, value2, value3)
            VALUES ('$valueForValue1', '$valueForValue2','$valueForValue3')
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                `value1`='$valueForValue1',
                `value2`='$valueForValue2',
                `value3`='$valueForValue3',
```

Comment: What indices/constraints do you have on the table? Besides *...all rows will need to change their 'value1' to a different value...* looks like a job for `UPDATE` statement rather than `INSERT` if you really meant *all rows*. Can you elaborate a little bit more on what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Forgive me, I am very new to MySQL. What do you mean indices/constraints? I haven't set any, if that helps.
How would I go about implementing that?

Comment: I need value2 and value3 to stay the same, but value1 should be updated every few months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to change a value of `value1` with `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause you have to have either a `UNIQUE` constraint or a `PRIMARY KEY` on `(value2, value3)`.

```sql
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD UNIQUE (value2, value3);
```

Now to simplify your insert statement you can also use `VALUES()` in `ON DUPLICATE KEY` like this

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (`value1`, `value2`, `value3`)
VALUES ('$valueForValue1', '$valueForValue2', '$valueForValue3')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value1 = VALUES(value1);
```

Here is **[SQLFIddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0365c/1)** demo

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The `UPDATE` action of the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause will only be executed if the row being inserted would cause the violation of a UNIQUE constraint. That means there needs to be a primary key or a unique index on the table.

If you want to modify existing rows, you'd really want to use an UPDATE statement.

To change the value in a column of existing rows, replacing 'oldvalue' with 'newvalue', you could do something like this:

```
UPDATE mytable
   SET col1 = 'newvalue'
 WHERE col1 = 'oldvalue'
```